# Cloudera Impala SQL TABLE CREATE with square brackets in column name

Tags: sql, jdbc, cloudera-cdh, impala

I have a statement in the form of:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (`hello_[3]` INT)
```

When i try to run it via JDBC or from hue, i get:

```
**AnalysisException: Invalid column/field name: hello_[3]**
```

trying other methods of quoting yields the same result:

`CREATE TABLE my_table ('hello_[3]' INT)
^ encountered: string literal expected: identifier`


`CREATE TABLE my_table ("hello_[3]" INT)
^ encountered: string literal expected: identifier`


`CREATE TABLE my_table ([hello_[3]]] INT)
^ encountered: [ expected: identifier`

I'm running CDH 5.3.0 unmodified and JDBC is type 4.1 v2.5.16.1018

To clarify: I need to be able to create tables with columns that contain square brackets in their names.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `hello_[3]` is not a valid column name. This is a limitation of the Hive metastore rather than Impala.

Impala uses a Hive utility to validate names. This is where the analysis failure occurs in ColumnDesc.java:

```
  public void analyze() throws AnalysisException {
    // Check whether the column name meets the Metastore's requirements.
    if (!MetaStoreUtils.validateName(colName_)) {
      throw new AnalysisException("Invalid column/field name: " + colName_);
    }
    type_.analyze();
  }
```

See MetaStoreUtils.validateName() for more details.

Comment: thanks Matt. It doesn't answer my question, but it does suggest that solution, if one exists, might not be worth the effort.

Comment: My point is that without modifying the Impala and Hive metastore code, there is no way to create columns with brackets in the name. It is not supported and there is no workaround, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Unfortunately this is a no-go for the use-cases that I have. Your response saved me a lot of time.